# Generate uniform references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

To generate references, I usually find the needed bibtex formats for references in Google Scholar, which may gives the following references:

> B.K. Chun, D.S. Ryu, W.I. Hwang, and H.G. Cho. 2006. An automated procedure for word balloon placement in cinema comics.
>   Advances in Visual Computing (2006), 576–585.
>
> Anastasios Dimou, Olivia Nemethova, and Markus Rupp. 2005. Scene change detection for H. 264 using dynamic threshold
>   techniques. In Proc. of the 5th EURASIP Conference on Speech and Image Processing, Multimedia Communications and
>   Service, Smolenice, Slovac Republic.

As you can see from the above example, the two references are not consistent, for example, their names format are different. How could I generate uniform references like the following:

> Chun, B.K., Ryu, D.S., Hwang, W.I., and Cho, H.G. 2006. An automated procedure for word balloon placement in cinema comics. Advances in Visual Computing 576–585.
>
> Dimou, A., Nemethova, O., and Rupp, M. 2005. Scene change detection for H. 264 using dynamic threshold techniques. In Proc. of the 5th EURASIP Conference on Speech and Image Processing, Multimedia Communications and Service, Smolenice, Slovac Republic.

P.S. It seems it's not easy to find all consistent bibtex formats for them in Google Scholar especially when the number of references are large.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't have first names for some entries, you can use a `bibtex` style which just uses initials and last names. These are not cross-references, by the way. That would be something like 'In section 3, I will explain what I mean.' Are you using `bibtex` or `biblatex`?

Comment: @cfr I am using `bibtex`.

Comment: So just use a suitable `bibtex` style. I can't remember but `natbib` might offer this option. Certainly some styles will. If you don't have first names for all authors, there really isn't much else you can do if you want consistency.

Comment: As @cfr hints, it is best to write your `.bib` files consistently. I, for one, try my best to get *all* information on the item (full names; for articles number, volume, pages, year; and so on). It is easy to throw information away...

Comment: @vonbrand Yes, but it is a huge task to prepare all information needed. I am looking for some automatic ways.

Comment: I add references to my `.bib` files as I download, read or note them. That way, I am never faced with too huge a task. Although this is sometimes annoying, it means all the information is on tap for whatever I need to cite whenever I need it. It also means I have a personal database of things I'm interested in and that is starting recently to become quite useful in itself. I think any automated solution (like using Google Scholar or whatever) will need adjusting. I use scripts to adjust entries I download but I still do manual tweaking on top. Like @vonbrand, I maximise information in `.bib`s.

Comment: @herohuyongtao, it is certainly a lot of work, but it can be distributed over time if you get in the habit of getting *all* data when you stumble on a reference. Even so, recently I went over my `.bib`s by creating a LaTeX file consisting of not much more than `\nocite{*}`, print out the result, go over it with a red pen, and filling in missing data. Took me the best part of two days. Caught a few errors and inconsistencies...

Comment: You may want to look into using the `apalike` bibliography style; amongst other things, it abbreviates first and middle names to their initials, it lists them *after* the surnames (separated by a comma), and it places the year information immediately after the author-related information. Using the `apalike` bibliography style doesn't mean you shouldn't try to double-check all fields of your bib entries from time to time and ensure that the information contained in the bib file is both correct and consistent.

Comment: Instead of obtaining the citations from Google scholar, which is second hand, you might want to try obtaining it from the publisher. These are usually quite complete. At least for the first given example this is possible. Since you are citing a specifical paper/ chapter i am quite confident you do also have access to the original or the electronical resource. In this case you should be able to extract all necessary information when editing the citation for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the way to make it consistent without manually editing.

Because I am writing a ACM journal paper of the Large Format Single Column, it actually offers a bibtex style called `acmlarge` that I can use to achieve this automatically. So by changing

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
```

to

```
\bibliographystyle{acmlarge}
```

I am able to generate the following consistent references:

[image]

---

**Note:** The above method may be only applicable for writing specific ACM journal papers. We may still need manually editing, as @cfr and @vonbrand commented, if the default template doesn't offer such options to us.